# trouble with using tokenizer.encode_plus

Tags: python, jupyter, transformer-model

#jupyter notebook

I'm trying to study BERT Classifier with https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pTuQhug6Dhl9XalKB0zUGf4FIdYFlpcX#scrollTo=2bBdb3pt8LuQ

In that colab, starting with "Tokenize all of the sentence....."

At that part, I have a trouble "TypeError: _tokenize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pad_to_max_length'"

```
**
input_ids = []
attention_masks = []

for sent in sentences:
    encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                    sent,                      # Sentence to encode.
                    add_special_tokens = True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
                    max_length = 64,           # Pad & truncate all sentences.
                    pad_to_max_length = True,
                    return_attention_mask = True,   # Construct attn. masks.
                    return_tensors = 'pt',     # Return pytorch tensors.
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538079/hugginface-transformers-module-not-recognized-by-anaconda)

"The problem is that conda only offers the transformers library in version 2.1.1 (repository information) and this version didn't have a pad_to_max_length argument."

So maybe the best option would be to uninstall and then reinstall transformers (this time with pip install instead of conda forge) or
create a new conda environment and install everything (via pip and not via conda).

Answer (score -1):

The function call looks a bit differently. You need to provide the padding strategy as string (`'max_length'` or `'longest'`).

```py
    encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                    sent,                      # Sentence to encode.
                    add_special_tokens = True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
                    max_length = 64,           # Pad & truncate all sentences.
                    padding = 'max_length',
                    return_attention_mask = True,   # Construct attn. masks.
                    return_tensors = 'pt',     # Return pytorch tensors.
               )
```

More info is on the [Hugginface documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html)