# huggingface-hub 0.0.12 requires packaging>=20.9, but you'll have packaging 20.4 which is incompatible

Tags: pytorch

huggingface-hub 0.0.12 requires packaging>=20.9, but you'll have packaging 20.4 which is incompatible

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will have to update the `huggingface-hub` through

```
pip install --upgrade huggingface-hub
```